# How to stop float to decimal conversion of jdbc template?

Tags: mysql, database, jdbctemplate

I'm retrieving data from the mysql database. One of my tables has a float data type value of 10. But when I retrieve it from jdbc template the value is retrieved as 10.0,

I cannot perform a decimal point conversion of decimal points. because the values that will get from that field can be different.

These are the sample values that will this attribute has.
0
13.2
13.2
13.2
15
20
20
18
20
20
20
0
38.342

This document shows that jdbc template performs a float data type to decimal data type conversion when retrieving data. 
https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html

Is there any mechanism to stop that conversion.

The real value that needs to get is 10.
If there is a value of 10.01 I should receive 10.01 as it is.

Comment: 10.0   and 10   are treated as equal, You dont have to worry about it.
You only need to worry if  10.0565 becomes  10.057  that's where you start to panic :)

Comment: Though they are equal I need them to be equal not in value, but in figures. Since this would be used in string comparison.

Comment: then in that case, you need to treat the data in string.  We can't stop the datatype just to skip .000 from happening.